# Why is chrome trusting an expired certficiate

Tags: google-chrome, certificate

So, the opposite problem of most folk.

I have a server with an expired certificate.  Chrome is connecting to the server and it is saying 'certificate is valid' even though it expired on January 18th, 2023.  The current date is Feb 2, 2023.

Does chrome have a grace period?  Is there some reason chrome has been forced to accept this certificate even though it is expired?

I would think that chrome should at least give a certificate warning, but nothing.  Is there some site setting where I had previously approved the expired certificate and it now trusts it?  I couldn't find a list of "trusted but bad" certificates anywhere.

FYI I've already installed the new certificate but IIS is still serving up the old one (needs a reboot.)  Is the certificate that is displayed in the browser different than the one actually used?

Comment: "Does chrome have a grace period?" - No; "Is there some reason chrome has been forced to accept this certificate even though it is expired?" - Is it currently in the list of certificates the system trusts. Look in the system's certificate store. I would need more specific information ot answer your question in more detail

Comment: Ramhound I didn't find it in the certificate store (certlm).  Which folder would it be in ?

Comment: Did you install the certificate, to the website, on the client in question? If you installed it, where you installed it, would have been up to you. I can't tell you where the certificate is, since I know nothing about the certificate, Root CA are typically stored with the other Root CA on the system.

Comment: Ramhound No, I used let's encrypt to install on the webserver.  I had connected originally with rdp from the client machine.  Now the client machine is trusting that certificate.  Chrome dutifully says "Expires on Wednesday, January 18, 2023 at 10:54:52 AM" in the same breath that it says "Certificate is valid"  I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: The only way it would be possible is if it's installed in the certificate store on the system. However, even if that were to be the case, you should be getting some sort of indication the certificate expiration date has been reached